# Spring - Is it possible to inherit a RestController with its RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

Let's say I have a parent entity `Vehicule` and some children entities `Car, Bike, Ship, Plane`. I have one generic repository which handles all entities:

```java
public interface VehiculeRepository<T extends Vehicule> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    // ...
}
```

I also have a generic `VehiculeService<T extends Vehicule>` class that take care of all the *BREAD* functions and some children services like:

```java
public class CarService extends VehiculeService<Car> {
    // ...
}
```

> NOTE: BREAD stands for Browse, Read, Edit, Add & Delete, aka CRUD

I'm wondering if I can create a generic `RestController` with its `RequestMapping` and inherit it for the child entities. something like

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/vehicules")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class VehiculeController<S extends VehiculeService> {

    private final S service;

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<VehiculeResponse> browse() {
        return service.browse();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@Valid @ModelAttribute VehiculeRequest request) {
        service.create(request);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public VehiculeResponse read(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return service.read(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void edit(@Valid @ModelAttribute VehiculeRequest request, @PathVariable Long id) {
        service.edit(request, id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        service.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create, let's say a `CarController` with the following code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/cars")
public class CarController extends VehiculeController<CarService> {
    public CarController(CarService service) {
        super(service);
    }
}
```

And have all the methods stated in parent correctly mapped & functionning without having to redefine them:

| Function Name | Mapped Request Method | URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| browse | `GET` | `http://HOST/api/cars` |
| create | `POST` | `http://HOST/api/cars` |
| read | `GET` | `http://HOST/api/cars/{id}` |
| edit | `PUT` | `http://HOST/api/cars/{id}` |
| delete | `DELETE` | `http://HOST/api/cars/{id}` |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, ***YES***
I tried it out & apparently the `RequestMapping` on the methods in parent class are applied correctly in child class, only the *root* `RequestMapping` on the controller itself has been affected. The requested behaviour is well achieved!

> *NOTE:* I marked the parent class as `abstract`